# Pass data attribute to a function

Tags: jquery

I have many div elements with same class name and different data-value attribute. When click over one div i want to pass its data-attribute to a function  and do some stuff depending on data-value attribute. How can i achieve that?

```
<div class="voto" data-value="1" onclick="VotaUtente.AggiungiVoto();">
    <img src="img/stella-1.png">
    <img src="img/stella-0.png">
    <img src="img/stella-0.png">
    <img src="img/stella-0.png">
</div>
<div class="voto" data-value="2" onclick="VotaUtente.AggiungiVoto();">
    <img src="img/stella-1.png">
    <img src="img/stella-1.png">
    <img src="img/stella-0.png">
    <img src="img/stella-0.png">
</div>
<div class="voto" data-value="3" onclick="VotaUtente.AggiungiVoto();">
    <img src="img/stella-1.png">
    <img src="img/stella-1.png">
    <img src="img/stella-1.png">
    <img src="img/stella-0.png">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
AggiungiVoto: function ()
    {
        $(".voto").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var nVote = $(e.currentTarget).data("value");
            console.log("nVote " + nVote);
        });
    },
```

I know that i can retrieve the data attribute using (".voto").data('value') but how can i pass the reference to the element i clicked to the function to determine the right value (ex. click on div with data-value="3" it returns 3) ?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$('.voto').on('click',function(){
    your_function_name($(this).attr('data-value'))
    });
```

Comment: @dorinocanciani can you post your code and html, for better understanding your needs...

Comment: Why do you think that the `attr` method works better for this than the `data` method?

Comment: @Guffa There is no full HTML and code, thus I suppose there is better to use jquery attr() method. May be after the full html and code will be posted your answer will right

Comment: I have updated the code. with this code if i click once on the div it returns nothing but in second click it returns the value twice..

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you think that the `attr` method would be better than the `data` method.

Comment: @Guffa See http://jsfiddle.net/k134k14f/. I made an validation of 3 different ways to get value from this attribute. Seems the data('value') also works well in this issue, and prop() return 'udefined'. You can choose any way you like

Comment: The `attr` method only works to get the attribute value, not the data value, i.e. if the data is changed using the `data` method, then `attr` can't be used to get that value. The `data` method will work to get the value both when it's set with `attr` and when it's set with `data`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".voto").click(function(){
    var voto_data_value = $(this).prop('data-value');
    function_name(voto_data_value);
});
```